# contact form error from a total noob

Tags: php, html, forms

I keep getting this message
 {"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}

wheneveri try to click submit, I'm pretty new with the whole coding thing and all i know about contact forms is that they should be connected to php to work.

This is how my code looks like on html:

```
<form  action="my-simple-contact-form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
Your name:<br>
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your email:<br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your message:<br>
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
```

I don't think the CSS is important.

and this is the php page

```
<?PHP
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
//print_r($_POST); die();
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")){
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
    }
else{       
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
    mail("xxx.xxxx@hotmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
    echo "Email sent!";
    }
```

?>

Help me fix this please!!!!

Comment: code works perfectly fine on my environment. what server are you using to test this?

Comment: chrome!, the layout of the code looks great it's just that I cannot seem to make it work, as in send messages when i click submit.

Comment: Chrome is the browser. You need to run a webserver like apache (XAMPP comes with that) that has PHP enabled

Comment: How do you open your site? What is written in your address bar?

Comment: wow we did not learn anything about apache in school xD, what i am doing now basically is editing my html and viewing it on chrome from dreamweaver before i set it live

Comment: but it does not submit

Comment: You submit button does not look correct. In the code you posted it is: `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">`. The type attribute should be "submit".

Answer (score 0):

for this error ,there are two case possible :
**you have mistake in form line**

```
<form  action="my-simple-contact-form.php" method="POST" 
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

in action: php file naming convention 'my-simple-contact-form.php' ,try camel case naming  convention  like mySimpleContactForm.php

**second case:**
your server support php? if yes, then try another example, if you get success ...
then resolve current issue

Comment: I fixed it!! i just misspelled the name of the php page! but thanks for your help!!!!